# mongoose v6 : TypeError: Invalid URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to migrate the mongoose from v5.10.0 to v6.7.2
I am following these two migration guides :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/etc/notes/CHANGES_4.0.0.md

My clusters use replicaset with 3 nodes.
I am using below config :

```
let options = {
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
        retryWrites : true,
        appName: 'testAppName',
        replicaSet: 'test-replicaset',
        maxIdleTimeMS: 150000, 
        wtimeoutMS: 0, 
        w: "majority", 
        autoIndex: false,
        maxPoolSize: 10,
        keepAlive: true, 
        connectTimeoutMS: 60000
    };
```

`mongoose.connect(mongo_server_uri + '/' + database, options);`

my mongo_server_uri looks like this :
`mongodb+srv://username:password@development.xyz.mongodb.net`
and database takes the value : 'abc'

so above would become:
`mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@development.xyz.mongodb.net/abc',options)`

I am using
mongoose : 6.7.2
mongodb server version : 4.4.17
node version : 16.16.0
os : macos Monterey v12.5.1

I get below error :

```
TypeError: Invalid URL: mongodb+srv://username:password@development.xyz.mongodb.net/abc
      at new URLImpl (/root_path/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL-impl.js:21:13)
      at Object.exports.setup (/root_path/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js:54:12)
      at new URL (/root_path/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js:115:22)
      at new URLWithoutHost (/root_path/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:74:1)
      at new ConnectionString (/root_path/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:126:13)
      at parseOptions (/root_path/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:200:17)
      at new MongoClient (/root_path/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:45:63)
      at /root_path/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:801:16
      at Promise._execute (/root_path/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
      at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/root_path/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
      at new Promise (/root_path/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
      at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/root_path/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:798:19)
      at Mongoose.createConnection (/root_path/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:359:10)
      at module.exports (/root_path/index.js:125:27)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async /root_path/bin/something.js:14:15,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined
} reason: TypeError: Invalid URL: mongodb+srv://username:password@development.xyz.mongodb.net/abc
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the username or password? "_If the username or password includes the following characters: `1: / ? # [ ] @` those characters must be converted using percent encoding._"

Comment: no i don't have any special characters in username and password fields